# How can I find a teacher?

Tags: lay-buddhism, teaching, meditation-teachers

What is the best way, or how would I even go about finding a Buddhist teacher or spiritual guide?  Thanks.

Comment: By practicing giving one derives near the Noble Domain, good householder. Yet it requires also to follow the 5 proper occasions for giving into.

Comment: How ever, a good and generous guide: [Into the Stream](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html)

Comment: Another guide: https://puredhamma.net/

Comment: there's advice for in in a number of texts. Kihwa's translation and commentary of the sutra of perfect enlightenment is, i think, one important example. the gist seems to be blame yourself if it's not working! that's a gloss. my two cents is make sure they are well thought of in monastic communities. hth

Answer (score 2):

If you have an interest in learning the Burmese system of Insight or Vipassana Meditation, which was popularized the world over by the Burmese Monk, Venerable [Mahasi Sayadaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahasi_Sayadaw), recommend his magnum opus "Manual of Insight," (pdf) which was translated into English by the Vipassana Metta Foundation of USA. Also recommend the utube video >Phra Noa Yuttadhammo - How to Meditate< as a visual supplement, for a novice  to get to grips with the subject. Incidentally, Ven. Yuttadhammo is a registered User of the Buddhism Stack Exchange.

Comment: oh, i thought my edit would be a suggestion rather than automatic. please do roll back the edit, if you want!

Comment: Ven. Yuttadhammo helped to start this site, no longer actively participates here.

Comment: @user3293056 The permissions [change with](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) 'reputation -- above 2000 you can [access moderators tools](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) if you want to -- and edits are automatic, though as you kindly said the OP can view [the edit history](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/posts/35463/revisions) (by clicking on the link which says "edited [some time ago]"), and from there do a "rollback" to a previous version if they want to.

Comment: @user3293056. Sorry, my response was to Kevin Hudson's original  question

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to familiarise yourself with Tipitaka and other Buddhist books first. Then familiarise yourself with the popular teachers available at the moment by browsing internet and Buddhist forums such as Stack Exchange, Dhamma Wheel and Sutta Central. There are many not so famous teachers. But when the student ready the teacher will appear!

Comment: wrt your last sentence: yes i have heard this said!